# How to use DataGridView to see database record?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, ado.net

This is my first ADO.NET project, I need to finish my professor casestudy. I want to create a windows form and put a Textbox to input the caseid and use a button find. When I click the find button, I can see the caseid and assigned solutions based on a SQL `Select` statement. I find an example and use a `SqlDataReader`, but when I click find, I cannot see the result on the form.

So, could you give me some suggestion how to design a datagridview here ?

Thanks
Sophia

I implement my code like this:

```
private void Find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string querystring = "SELECT * FROM AssignedSolution WHERE CASEID = @caseid";
        SqlCommand Vcom = new SqlCommand(querystring, vcon1);
        Vcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caseid", txtCASEID.Text);
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try
        {
            Vcom.Connection = vcon1;
            Vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            rdr = Vcom.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
            }

            Vcom.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error.occured" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            vcon1.Close();
            vcon1.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Comment: If you have ASP.Net project it means that probably want to create web form and need to use GridView. Right? DataGridView is not web component

Comment: Read this http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-tutorial.htm

Answer (score 0):

[DataGridViewRowCollection.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbs04kbx(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rdr[0], rdr[1], rdr[2], rdr[3], ..);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this (of course if your project is **WinForm**):

```
 private void Find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DataTable table = null;
     using (SqlConnection vcon1 = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
     {
         try
         {
             vcon1.Open();
             SqlCommand Vcom = vcon1.CreateCommand();
             Vcom.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM AssignedSolution WHERE CASEID = @caseid";
             Vcom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@caseid", txtCASEID.Text));

             using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Vcom))
             {
                 table = new DataTable();
                 adapter.Fill(table);
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             //Handle your exception;   
         }
     }

     dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How to from the beginning.
Add in HTML page:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
</form>
```

And in Default.aspx.cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillGridView();
    }
}
    public void FillGridView()
{
    try
    {
string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
        string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM YourTableName";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds, "YourTableName");

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch
    {
        Response.Write("<script> alert('Connection error') </script>");
    }
}
```

Also you need in web.config file to store your connection string

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Hi Alexej,Thank you for your code from HTML, I have filled out the from and let my professor to see. It sees good. Maybe next time I will begin implement it in HTML page

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sophia,

You Can Use SqlDataAdapter or SqlDataReader  with DataTable to show data in Datagridview Like

// Use SqlDataAdapter

```
    private void Find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConStr = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["strConn"]);
        SqlConnection vcon1 = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
        vcon1.Open();
        string querystring = "SELECT * FROM AssignedSolution WHERE CaseId = @caseid";
        SqlCommand Vcom = new SqlCommand(querystring, vcon1);
        Vcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caseid",Convert.ToInt32(txtCASEID.Text));


        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Vcom);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;                

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error.occured" + ex.Message);

        }

        finally
        {
            Vcom.Dispose();
            vcon1.Close();
            vcon1.Dispose();
        }
    }

    // Use SqlDataReader
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConStr = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["strConn"]);
        SqlConnection vcon1 = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
        vcon1.Open();
        string querystring = "SELECT * FROM AssignedSolution WHERE CaseId = @caseid";
        SqlCommand Vcom = new SqlCommand(querystring, vcon1);
        Vcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caseid", Convert.ToInt32(txtCASEID.Text));
        SqlDataReader dr = null;

        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dr = Vcom.ExecuteReader();              
            dt.Load(dr);  
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error.occured" + ex.Message);

        }

        finally
        {
            dr.Close();
            Vcom.Dispose();
            vcon1.Close();
            vcon1.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Kumar, Thank you for your answer, but when I copy this to the Find_click , the first line code:string ConStr = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["strConn"]); It shows an error at ConfigurationManager. Says: The ConfigurationManager does not exist in the current context. So, how I can fix this?

Comment: Hi Kumar, thank you so much! I have fixed the connectionstring myself. The application can work now, and my professor like it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi  Sophia , Thanks for appreciation , Its my pleasure.